# Flink Dynamic Table vs Kafka Stream Ktable?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

I was reading on the current several limitation of the joins in kafka stream such as Ktable KTable non-key join or KTable GlobalKTable ....

I discovered that Flink seems to support all of it. From what I read, A dynamic Table sound like a KTable.

I wonder if first of all, they are the same concept, and then somehow how does Flink achieve that, I could not find documentation about the underlying infrastructure. For instance i did not find the notion of broadcast join that happens with GlobalKtable. Is the underlying infrastructure achieving dynamic table distributed ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flink's dynamic table and Kafka's `KTable` are not the same.

In Flink, a dynamic table is a very generic and broad concept, namely a table that evolves over time. This includes arbitrary changes (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`). A dynamic table does not need a primary key or unique attribute, but it might have one.

- A `KStream` is a special type of dynamic table, namely a dynamic table that is only receiving `INSERT` changes, i.e., an ever-growing, append-only table.
- A `KTable` is another type of dynamic table, i.e., a dynamic table that has a unique key and changes with `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` changes on the key.

Flink supports the following [types of joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/joins.html) on dynamic tables. *Note that the references to Kafka's joins might not be 100% accurate (happy to fix errors!).*

- [Time-windowed joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#time-windowed-joins) should correspond to KSQL's `KStream`-`KStream` joins
- [Temporal table joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#join-with-a-temporal-table-function) are similar to KSQL's `KStream`-`KTable` joins. The temporal relation between both tables needs to be explicitly specified in the query to be able to run the same query with identical semantics on batch/offline data.
- [Regular joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#regular-joins) are more generic than KSQL's `KTable`-`KTable` joins because they don't require the input tables to have unique keys. Moreover, Flink does not distinguish between primary- or foreign-key joins, but requires that joins are equi-joins, i.e., have at least one equality predicate. At this point, the streaming SQL planner does not support broadcast-forward joins (which I believe should roughly correspond to `KTable`-`GlobalKTable` joins).

Comment: Thanks for the details Fabian! That is super helpful!

Comment: Thanks Matthias! Anything to correct from your point of view?

Comment: Sound accurate to me -- in an own answer, I said "both seem to be the same" as I focus on the "table" aspect, and skipped the part that Flink uses dynamic tables to model streams, too. It's good to get clarification how both concepts map to each other.

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure because I don't know all the details of Flink's "dynamic table" concept, but it seems to me it's the same as a `KTable` in Kafka Streams.

However, there is a difference between a `KTable` and a `GlobalKTable` in Kafka Streams, and both are not the exact same thing. (1) A `KTable` is distributed/sharded while a `GlobalKTable` is replicated/broadcasted. (2) A `KTable` is event time synchronized while a `GlobalKTable` is not. For the same reason, a `GlobalKTable` is fully loaded/bootstrapped on startup while a `KTable` is updated based on the changelog records event timestamps when appropriate (in relationship to the event timestamps of other input streams). Furthermore, during processing updates to a `KTable` are event time synchronized while updates to a `GlobalKTable` are not (ie, they are applied immediately and thus can be considered non-deterministic).

Last note: Kafka Streams adds foreign-key `KTable-KTable` joins in upcoming 2.4 release. There is also a ticket to add `KTable-GlobalKTabel` joins but this feature was not requested very often yet, and thus not added yet: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4628